# Вывод значения переменной в input

Tags: javascript, html

Есть у меня такой инпут

```
<input type="text" id="display" name="result">
```

И я хочу вывести в него значение переменной `result` с помощью следующей конструкции. Но она почему-то не срабатывает. Если сделать див с таким же `id`, то все работает. В чем проблема?

```
var result = 'vivod';
document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = result;
```

Comment: @Igor, на самом деле, свойство есть, но оно не используется для ввода/выдода значения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

потому что значение для инпутов задается с помощью свойства `value`

```
document.getElementById('display').value = result;
```

также оно будет работать для `select` и `textarea`